# How to anchor a Widget to the bottom of an Activity, if the widget that was at that position is made invisible

Tags: android-layout, android-relativelayout, android

I've got this situation, I have 4 widgets in a RelativeLayout in the same following order:

1. TextView
2. ListView
3. TextView
4. Button

This is the XML for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/pedidoClienteRelativeLayout">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameLabel"        
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:text="Customer Name" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ordersLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameLabel"
        android:layout_above="@+id/totalOrdersLabel"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/booksListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/totalOrdersLabel"       
        android:layout_above="@+id/confirmOrderButton"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Total" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/confirmOrderButton"       
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Confirm Order" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is more or less the result:

[image]

As you can see this works. The problem comes when from Java I have to make the Button invisible based on some conditions. Then the TextView that was above the Button has no control to reference using `android:layout_above="@+id/confirmOrderButton"` and for that reason the textview is shown at the top of the Layout and the ListView simply isn't shown.

I think that if I could remove the `android:layout_above="@+id/confirmOrderButton"` from the second TextView and add `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, that should fix the problem. The thing is that I have absolutely no idea how to do it, so I'd be really grateful if you could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly do you make the button invisible?

Comment: @AntonSavin The only way I know is :  `mConfirmButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `totalOrdersLabel` TextView's `android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing` to true.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/totalOrdersLabel"       
    android:layout_above="@+id/confirmOrderButton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:text="Total" />
```